# Error when create entity in jhipster

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jhipster

When I create entity using cmd , jhipster created file java , script but the database cant update ,no table was inserted .I started mysql and turn off application as i create entity .

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the java application only. It will execute the derby changelog